# Create multiple variables based on difference and ratios of existing variables in R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create multiple differences and ratios (in this particular case, but that could be anything) of existing variables at once in my dataset. The idea is to create the list of variables I want to work with (respectively the root, as it simplifies a lot the task), and use it further to create everything in one row using a data.table approach.

Here is a simple example with two roots, to show what I am looking for. The idea is to do the following

```
setDT(dataset)[ , root1.xy_diff := root1.x - root1.y]
setDT(dataset)[ , root1.xy_ratio := root1.x / root1.y]

setDT(dataset)[ , root2.xy_diff := root2.x - root2.y]
setDT(dataset)[ , root2.xy_ratio := root2.x / root2.y]
```

I would like to do it nicely, using one row, instead of copy pasting the same rows each time with a new root. I could do it for 10 variables, but not for thousands. And that is not very clever.

As shown above, I have prepared the dataset in such a way, that the variables I want to compute the difference/ratio always have the same root. Based on what I could find on the net, I was thinking about doing something like the following (using the same roots - difference is the difference between value x and value y and ratio is the ratio between x and y):

```
roots <- c("root1","root2")
roots.x <- paste0(roots,".x")
roots.y <- paste0(roots,".y")
names <- c(paste0(roots,".xy_diff"), paste0(roots,".xy_ratio"))

dataset[ , (names) := list(difference(), ratio())]

or

dataset[ , c(paste0(roots,".xy_diff"), paste0(roots,".xy_ratio")) := lapply(.SD, list_of_functions), .SDcols=roots]
```

The thing is that whatever I try, nothing works... I do not know how that should be written indeed.

I can add some data if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
library("data.table")
dataset <- data.table(root1.x = 1:3, root1.y = 4:2, root2.x = 5:7, root2.y = 9:7)
difference <- function(root) lapply(root, function(z) paste0("get('", z, ".x') - get('", z, ".y')"))
ratio <- function(root) lapply(root, function(z) paste0("get('", z, ".x') / get('", z, ".y')"))
roots <- c("root1","root2")

dataset[ , c(paste0(roots,".xy_diff"), paste0(roots,".xy_ratio")) := 
           lapply(c(difference(roots), ratio(roots)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))]
```

Which gives:

```
dataset[]
   root1.x root1.y root2.x root2.y root1.xy_diff root2.xy_diff root1.xy_ratio root2.xy_ratio
1:       1       4       5       9            -3            -4      0.2500000      0.5555556
2:       2       3       6       8            -1            -2      0.6666667      0.7500000
3:       3       2       7       7             1             0      1.5000000      1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Still I have one issue, due to the fact that I want to run that for about 5000 variables and not 2. I get the following warning:
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(setDT(Final), , `:=`(c(paste0(vars, ".xy_diff"),  :
  truelength (30854) is greater than 10,000 items over-allocated (length = 10854). See ?truelength. If you didn't set the datatable.alloccol option very large, please report to data.table issue tracker including the result of sessionInfo().
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your data long, perform the calculations by group, and then make your data wide again:

```
library("data.table")
dataset <- data.table(id = 1:3, root1.x = 1:3, root1.y = 4:2, root2.x = 5:7, root2.y = 9:7)
dtlong = melt(dataset,id.vars = "id",  measure.vars = patterns("root"), value.name = "root", variable.name = "variable")
dtlong[, c("varname", "ind"):=tstrsplit(variable, "\\.")]
dtlong[, `:=`(diff = root[ind=="x"] - root[ind=="y"],
              ratio = root[ind=="x"]/root[ind=="y"])
       , by = .(varname, id)]
dt_wide = dcast(dtlong, id~varname + ind, value.var = c("root", "diff", "ratio"))
```

which gives:

```
   id root_root1_x root_root1_y root_root2_x root_root2_y diff_root1_x diff_root1_y diff_root2_x diff_root2_y ratio_root1_x ratio_root1_y ratio_root2_x ratio_root2_y
1:  1            1            4            5            9           -3           -3           -4           -4     0.2500000     0.2500000     0.5555556     0.5555556
2:  2            2            3            6            8           -1           -1           -2           -2     0.6666667     0.6666667     0.7500000     0.7500000
3:  3            3            2            7            7            1            1            0            0     1.5000000     1.5000000     1.0000000     1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In the end, I chose to split the data in multiple tables, do the computations and join back. I think it is easier than transposing twice and having to think about ids and measures.